# UserDefault with nsmutabledictionary could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: swift, ios13, swift5

Im new to Ios development. Currently a one function returning the NSMutableDictionary which got store in the userDefaults. But when i retrieve the values from the userdefault its return the incorrect format of the NSMutableDictionary which fail to parse NSMutableDictionary and return back the error "could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' to NSMutableDictionary".

Function that return NSMutableDictionary

```
func initializeStructureOfControl () -> NSMutableDictionary {
        var parentSlideControl = NSMutableDictionary()

        var slideControl = NSMutableDictionary()
        slideControl.setValue(NSMutableDictionary(), forKey: UserDefaultKeys.fdtControlKey)
        slideControl.setValue(NSMutableDictionary(), forKey: UserDefaultKeys.pdtControlsData)
        slideControl.setValue(NSMutableDictionary(), forKey: UserDefaultKeys.eeControlsData)
        slideControl.setValue(NSMutableDictionary(), forKey: UserDefaultKeys.fbeControlsData)

        parentSlideControl.setValue(slideControl, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.slideControlKey)

        return parentSlideControl

    }
```

Initialize in the user default

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue( initializeStructureOfControl(), forKey: UserDefaultKeys.slideControlKey)
```

Retrieving the value

```
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.slideControlKey)
```

The value that got saved in userdefault:

```
  ▿ some : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : slideControlsData
      ▿ value : 4 elements
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          - key : fbeControlsData
          - value : 0 elements
        ▿ 1 : 2 elements
          - key : eeControlsData
          - value : 0 elements
        ▿ 2 : 2 elements
          - key : fdtControlsData
          - value : 0 elements
        ▿ 3 : 2 elements
          - key : pdtControlsData
          - value : 0 elements
```

The value that got return from the userdefault

```
▿ some : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : slideControlsData
      ▿ value : 4 elements
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          - key : fbeControlsData
          - value : 0 elements
        ▿ 1 : 2 elements  
          - key : eeControlsData
          - value : 0 elements {.....}
        ▿ 2 : 2 elements 
          - key : fdtControlsData
          - value : 0 elements {.....}
        ▿ 3 : 2 elements  
          - key : pdtControlsData
          - value : 0 elements {.....}
```

although it is working in the ios 12 or before device's (which returns the same value which was saved)but on ios 13 and later returns the above format string instead of saved one in user default.

Comment: Don't use *objective-c-ish* `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all. And don't use `setValue(forKey` unless you know what KVC is and you really need KVC. The error occurs because you never get a mutable collection type from `UserDefaults` with `object(forKey` not even in Objective-C.

Comment: what should i used alternative to NSMutableDictionary? as currently the whole application uses the NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Use Swift native type `[String:Any]`. It provides mutability for free as `var`iable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' to NSMutableDictionary

occurs because `object(forKey` returns an **im**mutable object. To get a mutable dictionary you have to create a new one for example

```
var slideControl = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.slideControlKey) as! NSDictionary))
```

---

However all `NS(Mutable)...` collection types are strongly discouraged in Swift. This is the native version

```
func initializeStructureOfControl () -> [String:Any] {
    let slideControl = [UserDefaultKeys.fdtControlKey : [String:Any](),
                        UserDefaultKeys.pdtControlsData : [String:Any](),
                        UserDefaultKeys.eeControlsData : [String:Any](),
                        UserDefaultKeys.fbeControlsData : [String:Any]()]
    return [UserDefaultKeys.slideControlKey : slideControl]
}
```

Save it to `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(initializeStructureOfControl(), forKey: UserDefaultKeys.slideControlKey)
```

And read it

```
var slideControl = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.slideControlKey)
```

The dictionary is mutable as `var`iable. But consider that Swift dictionaries are value types. You have to modify it in place. A more efficient solution might be custom structs instead of dictionaries and the `Codable` protocol to save the object in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Thanks vadian i will change all the NSMutableDictionary to [String:Any]